Error al obtener imagen desde base de datos MySQL
En mi base de datos tengo una tabla llamada "patrones" que contiene un campo "imagen" de tipo LONGBLOB.
En mi código, "imagen" es de tipo byte[], para poder guardar la imagen en la base de datos. Parece que se guarda correctamente porque en la base de datos aparece una cadena hexadecimal muy larga.
El problema es cuando quiero recuperar la imagen de la base de datos (es decir, el proceso contrario) para mostrarla en un control Image. Parece que no recupera bien la imagen, aunque los demás datos sí se recuperan perfectamente.
public List<Patron> obtenerListaPatrones(int idUsuario)
{
    DBBroker db = DBBroker.obtenerAgente();
    string query = "SELECT idpatrones, nombre, descripcion, imagen, tipo, idusuarios FROM patrones WHERE idusuarios = @idUsuario";
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idUsuario", idUsuario);

    List<Object> datos = db.leer(command);

    List<Patron> patrones = new List<Patron>();

    foreach (List<Object> fila in datos)
    {
        byte[] imagenData = fila[3] as byte[];

        // Imprimir los primeros bytes de la imagen como cadena hexadecimal
        if (imagenData != null && imagenData.Length > 0)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Datos de la imagen en hexadecimal: " + BitConverter.ToString(imagenData.Take(10).ToArray()));
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("No hay datos de imagen para esta fila.");
        }

        Patron patron = new Patron
        {
            idPatron = int.Parse(fila[0].ToString()),
            nombre = fila[1].ToString(),
            descripcion = fila[2].ToString(),
            imagen = imagenData, 
            tipo = fila[4].ToString(),
            idUsuario = int.Parse(fila[5].ToString())
        };

        patrones.Add(patron);
    }

    return patrones;
}

Añadí esos mensajes de Debug y siempre me salta el de "No hay datos de imagen para esta fila".
Por si sirve, también dejo por aquí el método "leer" que estoy usando en el trozo de código proporcionado anteriormente:
public List<Object> leer(MySqlCommand command) {
List<Object> resultado = new List<Object>();
List<Object> fila;
int i;
MySqlDataReader reader;

command.Connection = conexion;
conectar();
reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    fila = new List<Object>();
    for (i = 0; i <= reader.FieldCount - 1; i++)
    {
        fila.Add(reader[i].ToString());
    }
    resultado.Add(fila);
}
desconectar();
return resultado;}

Gracias de antemano.

El problema es que en el método leer, estás utilizando reader[i].ToString() para obtener los datos de cada campo, lo cual convierte todos los datos a una cadena. Esto es problemático para el campo de tipo LONGBLOB, ya que la imagen se almacena como un arreglo de bytes y no debería convertirse a una cadena.
public List<List<Object>> leer(MySqlCommand command)
{
    List<List<Object>> resultado = new List<List<Object>>();
    List<Object> fila;
    int i;
    MySqlDataReader reader;

    command.Connection = conexion;
    conectar();
    reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        fila = new List<Object>();
        for (i = 0; i <= reader.FieldCount - 1; i++)
        {
            // Chequea si el tipo de dato es un byte[] (BLOB)
            if (reader.GetFieldType(i) == typeof(byte[]))
            {
                fila.Add(reader[i] as byte[]);
            }
            else
            {
                fila.Add(reader[i]);
            }
        }
        resultado.Add(fila);
    }
    desconectar();
    return resultado;
}

Además, debes hacer lo mismo en el método obtenerListaPatrones:
public List<Patron> obtenerListaPatrones(int idUsuario)
{
    DBBroker db = DBBroker.obtenerAgente();
    string query = "SELECT idpatrones, nombre, descripcion, imagen, tipo, idusuarios FROM patrones WHERE idusuarios = @idUsuario";
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idUsuario", idUsuario);

    List<List<Object>> datos = db.leer(command);

    List<Patron> patrones = new List<Patron>();

    foreach (List<Object> fila in datos)
    {
        byte[] imagenData = fila[3] as byte[];

        // Imprimir los primeros bytes de la imagen como cadena hexadecimal
        if (imagenData != null && imagenData.Length > 0)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Datos de la imagen en hexadecimal: " + BitConverter.ToString(imagenData.Take(10).ToArray()));
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("No hay datos de imagen para esta fila.");
        }

        Patron patron = new Patron
        {
            idPatron = Convert.ToInt32(fila[0]),
            nombre = fila[1].ToString(),
            descripcion = fila[2].ToString(),
            imagen = imagenData, 
            tipo = fila[4].ToString(),
            idUsuario = Convert.ToInt32(fila[5])
        };

        patrones.Add(patron);
    }

    return patrones;
}

Recuerda que no es lo mismo trabajar con varchar que para los demas campos si te puede servir el hecho de leer como string, pero para algunos campos puede que esto no te sirva como es el caso, revisa la documentacion para que sepas que tipo de dato debes leer (varchar -> string, blob -> byte, integer -> int, etc...) para que en el futuro no te ocurra de nuevo
